# Turbolinks does not work with react-native webview

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webview, react-native, turbolinks

I am building a hybrid react-native + ruby on rails app. I am using the `onNavigationStateChange` in the `WebView` component to detect changes in the page, and use this to change the react-native navigation menu.  This works fine, but when I tried to use `turbolinks`, there can be a change in the page but the `onNavigationStateChange` is not triggered.

The  `onNavigationStateChange` is triggered is with following code

```
  render() { 
    return (
      <WebView
        ref={'webview'}
        automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
        source={{uri: SETTINGS_URL}}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        onNavigationStateChange={this.props.onNavigationStateChange}
        startInLoadingState={true}
        scalesPageToFit={true}
      />
    )
  }
```

This works normally, but if I turn on turbolinks, in the ROR app, the `onNavigationStateChange` no longer triggers.

How do I fix this?

Comment: how looks yr code ? how triggering that `onNavStateChange` ?

Comment: `turbolinks` is known to have issues with most javascript front end frameworks (dont quote me here). It's probably best to remove all `turbolinks` affiliated code. Whenever I used `rails` and a front end framework, I would remove it and everything would still function as intended. UNLESS you have specific needs for `turbolinks` I would remove it.

Comment: Have added a code snippet in response to /7urkm3n comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The turbolinks team appear to be working on a native integrations, with  [turbolinks-ios](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-ios) and [turbolinks-android](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-android).

Comment: Did you happen to fix this?

Comment: No, but I have posted a query on the turbolink compatibility project, https://github.com/reed/turbolinks-compatibility/issues/70.

Answer (score 0):

The good news is that I have tried the same react-native code with [Turbolinks 5](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) and the `onNavigationStateChange` is working. In fact everything I am using seems to work well with react-native.